# validated data from API update gives and empty dictionary

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hello guys am new to rest-framework and am facing a problem updating userprofile which I nasted user serializer in it's serializer. my sprofile serializer looks like this

```
class CompanyOwnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False, required=False)
    profile_pic = serializers.FileField(source='profile', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyOwner
        fields = "__all__"


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        data_user = validated_data.pop('user')
        instance.gender = validated_data.get('gender', instance.gender)
        instance.job_title = validated_data.get('job_title', instance.job_title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.location = validated_data.get('location', instance.location)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.longitude = validated_data.get('longitude', instance.longitude)
        instance.latitude = validated_data.get('longitude', instance.latitude)
        instance.save()

        if 'id' in data_user.keys():
            current_user = User.objects.get(id=data_user['id'])
            current_user.username = data_user.get('username', current_user.username)
            current_user.first_name = data_user.get('first_name', current_user.first_name)
            current_user.last_name = data_user.get('username', current_user.last_name)
            current_user.save()

        return instance
```

my issue that when I send data from post man I get error

```
KeyError at /profile-update/1/
'user'

Request Method: PUT
```

the data I am sending is

```
    "user": {
        "username": "kim_apps",
        "first_name": "",
        "email": "kimrop@examplemail.com",
        "last_name": "",
        "date_joined": "2019-06-06T21:00:32.612338Z"
    },
    "gender": "",
    "job_title": "",
    "description": "",
    "location": "KE",
    "address": "",
    "longitude": 36.23456,
    "latitude": -1.234567
}
```

can anyone help me the console says that key *user* is not found that is in the line

`data_user = validated_data.pop('user')`
I tried printing the validated_data but it gives an empty dictionary

I changed the question title coz I think that is where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

thanks for checking on it, I finally found a work around it is now workng, I remived my update function from serializer to my view like this

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = CompanyOwner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanyOwnerSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        validated_data = request.data
        print(validated_data)
        data_user = validated_data.pop('user')
        instance.gender = validated_data.get('gender', instance.gender)
        instance.job_title = validated_data.get('job_title', instance.job_title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.location = validated_data.get('location', instance.location)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.longitude = validated_data.get('longitude', instance.longitude)
        instance.latitude = validated_data.get('longitude', instance.latitude)
        instance.save()

        if 'id' in data_user.keys():
            current_user = User.objects.get(id=data_user['id'])
            current_user.username = data_user.get('username', current_user.username)
            current_user.first_name = data_user.get('first_name', current_user.first_name)
            current_user.last_name = data_user.get('username', current_user.last_name)
            current_user.save()
```

I dont get it but I thought they were just the same. anyway it is working that is allI wanted.